# How to add $USER to www-data group for me to edit the files freely on my project?

Tags: programming, 16.10, web-development

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 and just finished setting up LAMP Stack.
currently my Sublime Text keeps asking me authentication every time I edit a file.

Lamp Stack was installed using root user.

my /var/www/projects currently have www-data:www-data for it to work properly.

but I can't edit the files freely it keeps asking my password every time I hit save.

should I install Sublime Text as super user?

Comment: [Add user to existing Group](//askubuntu.com/q/79565) ?

Comment: apparently it didn't fixed my problem.
sublime text still keeps asking authentication every time I edit my files on my project.

Comment: my user and permission on my /var/www is currently www-data:www-data

Comment: Did you login again after adding your user to the group?

Comment: yes I did still not working
the command I did was sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER